# Mail link open my app on specific URL

Tags: android, cordova, url, intentfilter, crosswalk-runtime

I'm actually using *Crosswalk*. 
I have some hard restrictions about speaking about my project so i'll try to be as clear as possible.

---

When I open my app manually, Webview load the home *index.html* of the website.

But this website is used for **WebRTC** so, it send an invitation via an e-mail with specific URL.

- Is that possible to open **my own** application with URL that I just clicked ?

I checked for some `<intent-filter>` but I have no clue how to deal with the URL opening.

Hope someone have some solutions or clues.

**EDIT:**

```
<intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxx.xxx.com"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

With that I can open my application when I click on a link, but I still need to get the link url and set it as url loaded in my XWalkView.

**Example:**

https://xxx.xxx.com/join?xertfgf=1

When I click on that, my app open good, but know i want my XWalkView to load this.

Help :c

Comment: i dont get it, so you open your URL within your own app's WebView?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme?

Comment: I just want someting like : You open your email, see a link to join a conf, click on this link and that open my app ( with crosswalk webview inside ) @the given url

Comment: @Keval I edited, i just gonna work with Crosswalk so I can't use plugins :/

Comment: You'll have to find a way to be able to add native code to your hybrid application. Cordova provides an option to do so, but I am not known with Crosswalk-WebRTC. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

After setting `<intent-filter>` correclty, if you use Crosswalk ( it will work with classic or Cordova Webview ) just :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String link = intent.getDataString();
xWalkWebView.clearCache(true);
if(link!=null){
    xWalkWebView.load(link, null);
} else {
    xWalkWebView.load("file:///android_asset/index.html", null);
}
```